# Command to list files in the working directory of GIT

Tags: git

Is there any command to list files in the working directory of git ?

I know we have commands for the below:

1. To list files in branch (committed):  `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD`
2. To list files in staging directory:   `git ls-files -s`

But not able to find command to list files in the working directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The working directory is the place you're working in and where your files are actually spawned when you check out a given revision. So you want to check them out with your regular operating system command. That is, either `dir` or `ls` from `cmd` or an Unix shell, or the common file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
ls -R
```

Since this is the working directory, this is not a Git matter; just talk to the shell and ask it for the list.

Observe that, in the form I have given the command, the *.git* folder itself (the repo) is not listed, as it is "invisible". Which is good!

The same thing is true when you want to know the contents of a file. To learn what's in *myfile.txt* in commit `abcdef123`, you would say `git show abcdef123:myfile.txt`. But to learn what's in *myfile.txt* in the working directory, you don't talk to Git at all; you would say `cat myfile.txt`.